# Copy an Amazon EC2 Instance to use locally

Tags: amazon-ec2, virtualization, xenserver, debian-wheezy

Ok, so we have a spare server I have installed Debian Wheezy on, and setup Xen on for virtual machines. It has better performance than all our ec2 instances combined, and will cost less to run (for a few various reasons)

I would like to get the EC2 instances downloaded to my server, and converted to run for Xen, but im having difficulty finding anything specific. I did not setup the EC2 instances myself, and am not very familiar with them.

Everything I have found (which isnt much) just says "Do XYZ" and I have no idea how to do those. So being as specific as possible would be helpful.

Also, confusingly I see people writing in forums saying you can only export linux images (which mine are, Ubuntu images) but then I see on amazons export tool saying you can only export Windows server? Am I missing something here? Is that not the right place to be looking?

Thanks

Comment: Could you be more specific which tutorials say "Do XYZ" that you had trouble with? You say "being as specific as possible would be helpful" but the same is true for your **question**.

Comment: Sorry, I've looked at too many pages to find them in my history again, but basically they said along the lines of "Use amazons VM import/export tools" or some slight variation (sorry, should have just said that in the question)

Comment: You're going to have to find a Linux-specific tutorial. Frankly, though, the better way to do this is a configuration management system rather than downloading snapshots.

Comment: @ceejayoz linux tutorials such as ..... ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Amazon VM Export API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ExportingEC2Instances.html) to save in S3 an OVA version of your instance. Download it and restore it using XenCenter.